# Use BackgroundWorker to get message from client

Tags: c#, client-server, backgroundworker

I have a Client - Server application that needs to receive a message from the client.
This is the code to start listening on the server:

```
    private void startListening(TcpListener lisener)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        _socket = _lisener.AcceptSocket();
        connectionAcceptedEvent("Connection accepted from " + _socket.RemoteEndPoint);
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = _socket.Receive(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            message += Convert.ToChar(b[i]); // Message from client
        }
    }
```

This is the event when the server finishes receiving all the messages from the client. At this point, I need to get the message string:

```
private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Result` property of the arguments of each event handler to do this:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    e.Result = message;
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string message = e.Result as string;
    //...
}
```

On a side note, concatting each new character to `message`, one at a time, is a pretty bad idea.  You should be using a `StringBuilder` there to append the characters without creating an entirely new intermediate string each time.